# How to create equal frequency (depth) bins with D3?

Tags: d3.js, binning

You can create equal width bins with D3 like this:

```
const arr = [0, 0, 1, 10, 100, 102, 200, 253, 10000]
const bin_gen = d3.bin()
const bins = bin_gen(arr)
```

Puts the data into these bins:

```
[
    [
        0,
        0,
        1,
        10,
        100,
        102,
        200,
        253
    ],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [
        10000
    ]
]
```

with these thresholds:

```
[
    [0, 2000],
    [2000, 4000],
    [4000, 6000],
    [6000, 8000],
    [8000, 10000],
    [10000, 12000]
]
```

Instead, what I want is for there to be an approximately equal number of observations in each bin, with unequal threshold widths. Is it possible that you can only create equal width bins and not equal depth/frequency bins with D3?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your data in a sorted list, then you can simply take the non-overlapping chunks.

```js
// create dummy data, sorted by stringification
const arr = [...Array(23)].map((_, i) => i);
arr.sort();

// get chunk sizes
const n_chunks = 5;
const default_chunk_size = Math.floor(arr.length / n_chunks);
const n_initial_larger_chunks = arr.length % n_chunks;

let index = 0;
const chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < n_chunks; i++) {
    let sz = default_chunk_size;
    if (i < n_initial_larger_chunks) {
        sz += 1;
    }

    chunks.push(arr.slice(index, index + sz));
    index += sz;
}

console.log(chunks);
```

```
[[0, 1, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 2, 20, 21], [22, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: In my case, the length of `arr` will vary. I want the number of bins to vary as well. D3 automatically calculates what you refer to as `n_chunks` based on [Sturges' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Sturges'_formula).

Comment: I guess you could use `const n_chunks = d3.thresholdSturges(arr)`.

Comment: Your result is incorrect. `2` should be in the first bin, not the third. Seems to stem from incorrect sort logic.

Comment: The comment notes that they're sorted by stratification (it doesn't really matter, it's an arbitrary sort)

Comment: What are the thresholds for each bin?

Comment: It doesn't always work. If sorted `const arr = [0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 100, 102, 200, 253, 10000]` you will get `[[0,0],[0,1],[10,100],[102,200],[253,10000]]`, but how can `0` be in two different bins?

Comment: This is a good point that I hadn't considered. Given value counts of `[c_1, c_2, ..., c_n]`, you can probably do some dynamic programming to place boundaries to minimize the SSE from average group size.